# Android USB detected , but unable to read files from USB

Tags: android, usb

After USB detection on device, how can I read files from USB pendrive and how to get the path of USB? I tried this code this but it didn´t work.

```
  File f = new File("/storage/usbhost/");`
  f.isDirectory();
  File[] files = f.listFiles();
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Have a look at getExternalFilesDirs(). It can return up to three paths, The last one will be the pendrive. You will only be allowed to read. But that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> how to get path of USB

There is no useful "path of USB". Prior to Android 4.4, there was no official way to get to removable storage, and on Android 4.4+, you do not have access via the filesystem to arbitrary locations on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Use [the Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`) to allow the user to choose where content should be stored, which could include removable storage.

Answer (score 0):

If ur working on 24 API and higher

Try Using:

getStorageVolumes() on StorageManager

It will give you a list of storage volumes, which includes external storage and removable storage.

You can then use createAccessIntent() on StorageVolume to ask the user for permission to work with the volume. If permission granted, you get a Uri